# How can I change Eclipse color scheme for a specific file extension?

Tags: eclipse, color-scheme

I've installed [*Eclipse Debugger Plugin for v8*](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/using-eclipse-as-node-applications-debugger).
When a Javascript file is brought up from the remote connection, it has a `.chromium` extension.

[image]

Acutal color scheme for `*.chromium` files is not ideal but I haven't been able to figure out how to change it.

I went into `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations` and changed `*.chromium` file association from "**JS Editor**" to "**JavaScript Editor**" (used for `.js` files edition, and **having the color scheme I want**.)

[image]

However making this change had no effect.

I have the "Eclipse Color Theme" add-on installed and am using Eclipse version 4.2.1.M20120914-1800 running on windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I right clicked on one of the .chromium files and selected "Open With->JavaScript Editor" that file came up with the same editor as the js files. Doing this once must have fixed something in eclipse because now subsequently all .chromium files open up with the other editor.

Comment: It would be better to edit the default editor preferences rather than just open the file with another editor. This because sometimes opening with another editor does not solve the syntax coloring problem.